# TypeError: require(...) is not a function Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need help. I have this error when I run npm start:

```
/Users/telecreative/Documents/cafemates micro-services/cafemates-users-services/database/index.js:8
const pgp = require("pg-promise")(options)                                 ^
```

On another computer, script running, with node version and npm version was same:

TypeError: require(...) is not a function

```html
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/./../../.env'})
const promise = require("bluebird")
const options = {
  promiseLib: promise
}
const pgp = require("pg-promise")(options)

const config = {
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT
}

const db = pgp(config);

module.exports = db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `npm install --save pg-promise bluebird` from the project root and then reload the app.

Comment: Check your package.json and the versions of each pg-promise.

Answer (score 1):

This: `require("pg-promise")` simple does not return function.

Therefore when you use `require("pg-promise")(...)` it tries to use it as function and then fails, because it is not a function.

You can try `console.log(require("pg-promise")))` to see whats inside.

Comment: console and output..
{ PGPromise: [Function] }

Comment: @DickyPerdian So what about `require("pg-promise").PGPromise(options)`

Comment: solved, i install one by one module ,and working ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved
wrong me, I copy the json package., from the existing one, the best way should be to install one by one.